# HTML EMAIL 3 colum works in outlook 2003 but fails in 2007 onwards

Tags: html, email, outlook

I have an html email with a 3 column layout in it. Its displays fine in outlook 2003 but fails in 2007 onward. code can bee seen here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fAHGw

Could someone tell me why padding-left works in outlook 2003 but fails in outlook 2007?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dmitry has noted Outlook 2007/2010/2013 uses the wonky Word rendering engine and it renders a lot of HTML differently from regular Web browsers.

Your concern is addressed in Tip #7 among other Tips for Outlook 2007+ here:
http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C6/tips_and_tricks_outlook_07-13#outlook07-13_tip7

The solution is to move the padding from the `<p>` element to the `<td>`

Answer (score 1):

Because in Outlook 2007 and up, it is Word that renders HTML, not IE.

Comment: Could you explain this in more detail?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking - Word renders HTML differently from Internet Explorer.